# XmlSerializer.Serialize() fails to update XML file

Tags: c#, .net

So far I've followed the textbook route of adding adding data to an XML file; first, I created a class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Note
    {
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

And then done this:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string stringToAdd = textBox.Text;
        Notes.Add(stringToAdd);

        using (StringWriter myStringWirter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer myXML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Note));

            Note myNote = new Note();
            myNote.Notes = stringToAdd;

            myXML.Serialize(myStringWirter, myNote);

            using (StreamWriter myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter("Notes.xml"))
            {
                myStreamWriter.Write(myStringWirter);
            }

        }
```

But Notes.xml doesn't get updated. Why?

Edit. Now it works. Just by using List instead of Note.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. File gets created and filled with data with your code

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Any specific error thrown to you?

Comment: No error. I just debugged it and stringToAdd gets a value, MyNote.Notes gets a value, BUT myStringWriter only gets two characters, \r and \n. Why?

Comment: Do you want to append data to a file or to rewrite it completely?

Comment: Why bother with the `StringWriter` why not just serialize directly to the `StreamWriter`?